# Filtering characters from a string in python. (if the characters are in string2, filter them from string1)

Tags: python, string, character, filtering

I've been having a syntax issue with this code.  I get a syntax error on the if statement line.  The purpose of this code is to filter out the characters from string 2, and reprint string 1 without them.  I think my logic is correct in how I've written it out (for loop to check if the character is in both strings, and then an if statement to filter out those characters from string2).  But I'm really crappy so I probably did something wrong.

```
def filter_string(str1, str2):
    newstr = ""

    for c in str1 and str2:
        if c == str1 and != str2:
            newstr += newstr + c
            break
    return newstr
```

Thanks for the help!

Comment: python has a lot of english-language-like constructs, but you can't just construct random sentences and expect them to do what you want them to.  You have a lot of bugs in the above that stem from this: `for c in str1 and str2:` and `if c == str1 and != str2:` are two such examples.  I suggest opening up a python tutorial and starting from the beginning - fancy `str.translate` or `''.join(gen expression)` answers are not going to teach you much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want something very similar to your first attempt, this will work:

```
def filter_string(str1, str2):
newstr = ''
for c in str1: 
    if c not in str2:
        print c
        newstr += c

return newstr
```

Comment: Thanks a lot.  Didn't consider just arranging the for and if like that.

Answer (score 4):

Here's how I'd do it in Python 2:

```
def filter_string(s, remove):
    '''given a string, s, remove characters in string, remove'''
    return s.translate(None, remove)
```

If you're in Python 3:

```
def filter_string(s, remove):
    return s.translate(str.maketrans('','',remove))
```

Or if you want compatibility across Python versions:

```
import re
def filter_string(s, remove):
    return re.sub('[' + remove + ']', '', s)
```

Either way, here's usage:

```
>>> filter_string('foo (*& bar', '&(*')
'foo  bar'
```

---

Here's timing, for Python 3 on my machine:

```
import timeit

setup = """
def filter_string_1(s, remove):
    return s.translate(str.maketrans('','',remove))

import re
def filter_string_2(s, remove):
    return re.sub('[' + remove + ']', '', s)
"""

timeit.timeit("filter_string_1('foo (*& bar', '&(*')", setup)
timeit.timeit("filter_string_2('foo (*& bar', '&(*')", setup)
```

For me returns:

```
1.6555187609919813
2.7981851549993735
```

So translate is even faster than regex for this trivial example.

Answer (score 0):

Sticking fairly closly to your initial attempt:

```
def filter_string(s, remove):
    result = []

    for c in s:
        if c not in remove:
            result.append(c)

    return "".join(result)

print filter_string("foo (*& bar", "(*&)")
```

**Note:** This isn't terribly very efficient as you're creating a list to store a list of characters of the new string that don't match the remove iterable and finally returning a new string by joining the `result` list with an empty string.

A better approach is to simply use the `str.translate()` method:

```
>>> "foo (*& bar".translate(None, "(*&)")
'foo  bar'
```

Here's some performance comparisions between the two approaches:

```
$ python -m timeit -s "from foo import filter_string" "filter_string('foo (*& bar', '(&*)')"
foo  bar
100000 loops, best of 3: 2.32 usec per loop

$ python -m timeit "'foo (*& bar'.translate(None, '(*&)')"
1000000 loops, best of 3: 0.265 usec per loop
```

The later approach is approximately 10x faster.

Comment: Can you please convert `remove` to a set, use list comprehension and compare the results?

Comment: Looks like the set would be a very small improvement, plus you'd need to overcome the relatively larger time it takes to convert to set - `>>> timeit.timeit("'i' in alpha", setup = "alpha=set('abcdefghi')")
0.047739225992700085
>>> timeit.timeit("'i' in alpha", setup = "alpha='abcdefghi'")
0.057853144011460245`

Comment: I know for a fact that the builtin ``str.translate`` will be faster as the underlying implementation will be in C/CPython.

Answer (score 0):

Certainly there are multiple ways to do this. Personally this is the simplest logic to folow:

```
def filter_string(str1, str2):
    str3=''
    for c in str1:
        if c not in str2:
        str3+=c
    return (str3)
```